# Free photo sharing site with excellent security features

Tags: web, sharing

I am organizing the memory book for our local elementary school.  For each of our school events, we will have a volunteer take photos.  I need a site where the various volunteers will be able to upload photos in batches.  I will then need to easily view and select for the memory book.  Simple photo edit features like red-eye will be appreciated.  As well as an easy method for downloading.  I don't think we will need a ton of space.  Because these are photos of children who may not be aware that their photos have been taken, my biggest concern is protecting the images.

I would rather not require the photographers to have to make an account for the site (they are volunteering).   I am willing to share the password with the photographers.  Debating if I should change the password frequently.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason they need to be on a site?  For a situation like this, why not simply download the cards to a drive locally before they leave?  Services like dropbox can also be used for exchanging files directly, but I'd be hesitant to put anything sensitive on the Internet unless there is a good reason to do so.

Comment: If all that matters is security and protection, borrow the volunteers a camera with a memory card - then have them return the unit with the images after the event. If that isn't an option, ask them to bring you their memory card when the event is done. If security is less important, use dropbox, box, google drive, etc. Using a "photo sharing site" isn't what I'm hearing. You want a private file sharing service.

Comment: What @dpollitt suggests is exactly what happens when schools visit my work. The unfortunate thing is that the camera we have to borrow from them is a cheap P&S when there are a number of decent photographers on site :-(

Comment: Upload via email is available on a number of sites and is completely secure against download if the site is otherwise protected.

Answer (score 1):

The OP says "we will have a volunteer take photos".  Since there is only one volunteer per event, this makes it easier.  After the event, you can borrow their card and make a copy.  You may want to have spare cards in case the volunteer is uncomfortable with you handling their cards which may have photos from outside the event.

For light editing, there are several applications available (both free and paid).

This approach maintains security, you don't have to wait for the volunteer to upload and there's no fussing over accounts and passwords.

Photo sharing sites can be tricky.  Sharing accounts or uploading photos that you did not take gets into a gray area.

Answer (score 0):

Why not http://flickr.com/ ? Just set all photos to private.

Answer (score 0):

Its not free, but Smugmug allows you to configure guest upload, so there is no need for separate accounts, just provide the link to the volunteer. It has basic editing, as well as integration with PicMonkey for more extensive editing.

You can also password protect a gallery/site, and provide the password to your volunteer. You can also simply hide the gallery, that can be reached only if you know the proper URL.